# Missouri raptors have wild hairdos

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

**Across:**

> 1. URL for commercial clothes (7)
>   3. Steal each commodity (6)
>   5. One gut was queasy, you can stick it out (6)
>   7. Throw caution to the wind and sell art (7)
>   9. Endlessly care for vehicle (3)
>   10. March saint does prank next to Dad (7)
>   12. Martha upset by one missing end of race (8)
>   15. Loose way of communicating (5)
>   18. Public school at standardized test (4)
>   19. Mistake when supporters back university (5)
>   21. Warm states in south remove restriction (7)
>   22. Engage cross by odd knitted item (3,4)
>   23. Keats chewed meat (5)
>   24. Damp filling of Elmo is trouble (5)
>   26. Ag nerd spoiled plot (6)
>   27. Stalk life-saving cells (4)
>   29. Missouri raptors have wild hairdos (7)
>   33. Endlessly suave in the city (5)
>   34. Lead crazily right to Chicago planetarium (5)
>   35. I am in neither script of old movies (5)
>   36. Truth is 11-0 in morning (5)
>   38. Buried in stress, even though it's an inning for stretching (7)
>   41. I am not in Bulgarian city seat (4)
>   44. Former Astro chewed many, many bytes (6)
>   45. Evenly, Lear invites Bert's pal (5)
>   47. Broken pot just the start of big nerd (5)
>   49. Quick break if pot's tip is reversed (3,4)
>   50. Spy agency takes in double-crosser who swallowed ring in Eastern European country (7)
>   52. Sample first ingredients of tacos and salads tomorrow evening (5)
>   53. Zeus changed channel (4)
>   54. Hobbit woman in front of broken door (5)
>   56. Initially, cadets on loans used money brought in at university (8)
>   58. Garment unraveled at sewer (7)
>   59. Modern core of poem (3)
>   60. Spanish gold found around country of Disney town (7)
>   61. The worm heard argument (6)
>   62. Snake language (6)
>   63. Net vision heard Stack Exchange is one (7)

**Down:**

> 1. Ana enumerates out loud for therapists (8)
>   2. Improvised a skit for Alaska city (5)
>   4. Sharp raw noodles contain shrimp (5)
>   5. Crown heads of ten international and royal agents (5)
>   6. Bets around as monsters (6)
>   7. A mom sounds obvious (8)
>   8. Men gut fishy spice (6)
>   11. Disputed region is a loud type of sweater (7)
>   12. Dank smell in emu skins (4)
>   13. Unpredictable and held in computer memory (6)
>   14. Headless trout rule type of country music (6)
>   16. Crazy Alan raging for mathematical relaxation (10)
>   17. Cow shred blended into creamy soups (8)
>   20. At first, happy youth might not sing songs (5)
>   25. Washington city filled wrap before Massachusetts (6)
>   28. North side of Chicago suburb is Hansen (4)
>   30. Unthinking, foiled a wild theft (10)
>   31. This stump (6)
>   32. Rex posed inside convention (4)
>   34. Mountain roast spilled taco (2,6)
>   37. Bush Jr. will speed up endlessly while my guitar does this gently (5)
>   39. Clover sprinkled around fastening tape (6)
>   40. Child swirling in central point of whirlpool (3,3)
>   42. Release Han from climbing movie (4,4)
>   43. Leader of Nokia swears recklessly by solutions (7)
>   46. Mother drops down loudly for remainder of division (6)
>   47. Info shattered a bit (4)
>   48. Hunk of meat pie (8)
>   51. Insist weirdly as rest (6)
>   55. No bumble bees are fat (5)
>   56. Rookie jazz player around Delaware (5)
>   57. Heartless mirage is wobbly in picture (5)

*This is the first full cryptic I've written -- any feedback, good or bad, is appreciated!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the completed grid:

> [image]

And some comments, as requested.

> Not bad at all, but I have a number of quibbles. Several "indirect anagrams" -- i.e., the answer, or a part of the answer, consists of an anagram of a word indicated only by a definition. That's generally viewed as Bad because there are just way too many possibilities. Some rather dodgy homophones; I particularly dislike 61a and 7d (though the latter might be partly a difference in accents). A few definitions aren't really *definitions*; e.g., "relaxation" doesn't define LAGRANGIAN; there is a mathematical technique called "Lagrangian relaxation" meaning relaxation of the Lagrangian, but "this word sometimes goes together with that word" does not a definition make :-). In general, the clues often feel too "straightforward" -- there's only one plausible way to parse them as crossword clues and/or the *most obvious* parsing of the surface reading is also the correct way to parse them as clues. On the other hand, the grid has rather little "checking" -- only a small fraction of the cells are shared between multiple clues. This means that if the solver gets stuck on one clue it can be very difficult to make progress -- and when some of the clues involve not-entirely-fair constructions like indirect anagrams, this is particularly irksome. (That was one reason why 61a annoyed me: it was a slightly iffy clue *and* its only interaction with the rest of the crossword was an E at the end of it.)

Credit where due:

> I posted this with 10a, 18a, and 11d unsolved. OP kindly gave me a nudge (well, a shove) for 18a, which was enough to get the others -- though as it happens El-Guest also solved 10a about 30 seconds before I did :-).

Comment: *Thank you* for all of this feedback. All your points are well taken. I didn't realize that "indirect anagrams" were a no-no. About the "relaxation" clue, would "type of" help if it was before "relaxation" (or before "mathematical") in the clue?

Comment: About 18a: You might be overthinking it a bit.

Comment: I'd also like to note that apart from the questionable checking in some places, the grid isn't even connected! There's a line of black squares going roughly vertically, splitting the grid in two.

Comment: Yes, adding "type of" would be an improvement (at least in terms of clue soundness; might not be an improvement to the surface reading).

Comment: Oh, is there a thing called the PSAT? That would do it, I guess. Though I don't recall ever seeing "public school" written as PS, not least because "private" also begins with P...

Comment: D'oh, and KASHMIR (which btw I don't like because the wool is actually named for the region, so although it's a homophone it's also sort of not).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: 10A is likely PATRICK, def: March saint, parsing is PA (Dad) next to TRICK (prank)

Comment: I just got that too :-).

Comment: PS = Public School is definitely a Canadian/North American thing, too — I see it here all the time, but that may be because private schools are either (a) less common or (b) sometimes known as “Colleges”, especially in the Toronto area.

Comment: Nice! Looks like you put this one to bed before you put yourself to bed. Great job, @GarethMcCaughan!

Comment: Yeah. Actually going to bed would have been the smarter move overall, but it's nice to finish things.

Comment: Fair enough. It’s bedtime for me now, and I think I’m 5 hours behind you...rest easy!

Comment: Holy moly, I didn’t even notice that the grid isn’t connected. Oops!

Comment: About PS: Lots of New York schools are named P. S. [some number] ([examples](https://www.schools.nyc.gov/find-a-school?keyword=PS&grade_levels=&school_borough=Brooklyn&pg=1)); too localized though I guess.

Comment: Anyway thanks for trying out my puzzle and providing excellent feedback.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Combination of answers with credits

Across

9) Endlessly care for vehicle (3)

> CAR [care - e, def: vehicle]

62) snake language (6)

> PYTHON [double def.] @Tojrah

Down

20) At first, happy youth might not sing songs (5)

> HYMNS [(h)appy (y)outh (m)ight (n)ot (s)ing, def: songs]

51. Insist weirdly as rest (6)

    > ASSERT [anagram of AS REST]

Answer (score 3):

Partial

Across

62) snake language (6)

> PYTHON (programming language)

Comment: nice one, combined answers, +1!